# Splitting an array in a textfile (writing)

Tags: c#, arrays, split

for example my array is

```
string[] array = new string[] {"A", "B", "C"};
filename = "hello.txt";
```

how can I make it so it saves in a textfile with "**;**" in between every letter?

Thanks

Comment: Please upload some code which you have written so far and show us where you have errors

Comment: Have you tried anything or searched at all?

Comment: That's not called splitting, it's the opposite - *joining*.

Answer (score 3):

At a minimum:

```
File.WriteAllText(filename, string.Join(";", array));
```